# Use Parted Magic with YUMI

Tags: boot, usb, syslinux, yumi

I've tried putting parted magic versions on an flash drive using YUMI but every time I get an missing file error stating:

This application has raised an unexpected error and must abort.
[45] File or directory does not exist.
os.debian.52

The flash drive is working and formatted with FAT32 as verified through gparted. YUMI also works successfully when I put Kali linux on it. As an alternative I tried multibootusb, which successfully puts parted magic on the USB drive but then it apparently doesn't do it correctly because after booting parted magic cannot find the SQFS file and is unable to load the GUI.  According to this [thread](http://reboot.pro/topic/20472-hbcd-pmagic-2012-10-10sqfs-file-not-found/) it may be a common problem with creating USB utilities.  If there's a more appropriate forum for this just let me know.